# When running my program on localhost, it can't find .js files, nor the source of my bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a program that when stating the script locations it is able to locate them (it gives me the recommended folder names, etc., but when running the program I keep getting

> "GET http://localhost:8080/js/admin.controller.js"

errors.
My files are in resources with

- angular
- bootstrap
- js
- static (html files)

**Included in HTML Files:**

```
<script src="../js/admin.controller.js"></script>
<script src="../js/admin.factory.js"></script>
<script src="../js/admin.service.js"></script>
```

I get out of the folder, enter js, where it recommends the path, and it gives no errors at compile time. Yet I'm still getting the GET errors at runtime or when I try to access bootstrap/angular. I've also tried accessing by `href`.

Anyone know why? I would greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't think putting `../` is not an actual thing for script / img srcs or hrefs. What's are the folders that `..` are meant to fill in?

Comment: Try it without the ../js.   Where is your html being pulled from?

Comment: Where is the html loaded from (what url)? How is your folder structure with the files set up? Can you show a tree with the files?

Comment: show us your folder structure please

Comment: 1)Resources --> A) Js -> admin.controller.js      b) static --> home.html

Comment: sry it won't let me format it

Comment: put the details in the question

Comment: edit your post to add informations

Comment: Added, sry, still new! Added a pic

Comment: I think the static folder is served as public which means all your static assets(js,CSS,etc) need to go in static folder or change which folder is served as public

Comment: We would need to see how your server is serving the static files.

Comment: If you're accessing your `index.html` as `localhost:8080/static/index.html`, then this should work.  But, I'm guessing you're accessing it as `localhost:8080/index.html`, which would explain why it's not working.  What are you using as server?

Comment: @Molda: I did this and am now getting another error, "Module 'mobileHomeApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."  Not sure if that is relevent... but the other errors disappeared

Comment: @KevinB: What do you mean by this? How do I go about that

Comment: @caasjj I am accessing it as localhost:8080/index.html, if I try the other way I get a 404

Comment: @Logan Stewart open dev tools(F12 in chrome) in your browser and check the file containing the missing module is there I ques it won't be there or you misspelled it (typo)

Comment: @Molda under sources, I can see all the of my JS files ( I don't know if it was like this before I moved them all to the static folder) just the error above, I'm assuming that is another bug I can now try to fix, since I assume it sees them?

Comment: @Logan Stewart  If the file is there than it means now you have problem with your javascript. So maybe typo or some syntax error in js. Good luck with that :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Check your File Structure

If your app is not finding your js files your not giving the correct src. Your file structure should be like this for your main app or something simmilar

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app.module.js
│   ├── app.routes.js
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── about
│   │   │   └── about.html
│   │   ├── contact
│   │   │   └── contact.html
│   │   ├── home
│   │   │   ├── homeCtrl.js
│   │   │   ├── homeService.js
│   │   │   └── partial-home.html
│   │   ├── login
│   │   │   ├── loginCtrl.js
│   │   │   ├── login.html
│   │   │   └── loginService.js
│   │   └── services
│   │       └── services.html
│   └── shared
│       └── navigation-bar 
│           ├── navbarDirective.js
│           ├── navbarService.js
│           └── navigation-bar.html
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.css
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── img
│   │   └── homeBanner.png
│   └── js
│       └── ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js
├── index.html
├── npm-debug.log
└── README.md
```

## Index.html

Notice that Index.html is at the root of my app this should always be the case so you are just going into folders to retrieve scripts etc.

## Example

If you were to try to get the javascript files from the above file structure your index page would look something like this

```
<!-- Angular Modules -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.module.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/home/homeCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/home/homeService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/shared/navigation-bar/navbarDirective.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/shared/navigation-bar/navbarService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/login/loginCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/login/loginService.js"></script>
```

## Adding Angular

In the head of the index page I have added Angular, this is just to make sure it loads fast in my project along with bootstrap.css and ui.bootstrap.

here is what the head looks like

```
<title>My Web App</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
<!-- Angular links -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<!-- angularBootstrap link -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://angularjs.org/favicon.ico" />
```

## Conclusion

Hope this gives you a better idea of structure and calling scripts. feel free to ask me any questions and I'll update this answer.

Comment: Great comment. I recreated the project using the angular setup, which was exactly like you stated. This makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Logan. I have this type of app as a shell on github if you would like to fork or clone it be my guest. [here](https://github.com/joeLloyd/DoingAngularRight) is a link to the angular app. and [here](https://github.com/joeLloyd/GettingMEAN) is my mean app template. Ive written some comments in both but throw me a message on here if you want me to explain something. the Angular app is split, each feature is a module. this is best practice for development.

Comment: Awesome! That looks great! Will definitely help me out... new to angular and bootstrap. Thanks bud!

Comment: You should really update the file structure, as you should have a main.js and app.js for modules...

Comment: @TGarrett feel free to make some updates to my answer, I have not worked with angular 1 in a long time. I have a large amount of answers and keeping them all up to date would take up all of my time.

Answer (score 7):

The reason you can't access `../` files is that your `index.html` is being accessed from the root of your server.  All files must therefore be *below* that directory.  You have the option of changing the root of your server (which would then mean e.g. serving your index from `http://localhost:8080/<pathFromRoot>/index.html` (not great!) or moving your asset directories below the directory containing `index.html` - my recommendation.

You can also move the root of your server, put `index.html` there and then use relative paths to all your assets.  This is probably the most common thing done.